# underscore-like API documentation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, documentation, underscore.js

Is there any specific tool that is used by underscore authors to generate documentation? I suppose so because I've found at least three projects documented in the same style, but I can't find any information about such tool used by any of those projects.

- [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)
- [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/)
- [bookshelf](http://bookshelfjs.org/)

Comment: I don't know if there is, but backbone.js and underscore.js were both created by the same person ([Jeremy Ashkenas](http://ashkenas.com/)).

Comment: Probably it's just the same html template. Or Jeremy Ashkenas use some engine to generate static html. Like jekyll or something similar..

Answer (score 5):

In contrast with the previous answer, I'm pretty sure they don't use jsDoc.  Jeremy Ashkenas is the creator also of [Docco](https://github.com/jashkenas/docco), and you can still see Underscore [documented with docco](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html).  But the main documentation seems to be using something else, and it's not jsDoc.  The evidence is clear:  Look a the source code and there's no jsDoc tags!

More than that, it's also clear that the documentation is generated entirely externally to the source code itself.  If you examine http://underscorejs.org/#chaining, you will see that it includes the text "When you've finished the computation," but a search of the git repo for "the computation" finds no hits.

Ashkenas has some relationship with [DocumentCloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocumentCloud), and I don't know much about them, but I'm guessing that something about their advertised document annotation capabilities are in play here.  But I really don't know.

I wish I did, as I like the Underscore/Backbone documentation better than many others, and I have a project that's getting popular but really needs some decent documentation more than just the [Docco](https://rawgit.com/CrossEye/ramda/master/docs/ramda.html) we have now.